# CM Concrete with Latin Modern bold in LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, opentype, latin-modern

With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, how do I use Concrete (or any other font family that already has a bold) as main font but use Latin Modern bold as bold? This doesn’t work:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={Latin Modern Roman Bold}]{CMU Concrete}
```

Because apparently there’s no family named “Latin Modern Roman Bold”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell `fontspec` to select the bold variant by appending `/B`.

Just for reference, there is also `/I` for italic and `/BI` for bold-italic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={Latin Modern Roman/B}]{CMU Concrete}
\begin{document}
Hello \textbf{World!}
\end{document}
```

[image]